# イベントが設定されてるかどうかを知りたいif文のエラーが原因が知りたい。

Tags: c#

Main関数部のコメント部なのですが、イベントハンドラー？がnullだったらイベントが設定されていなのでコメント部のようなコードを書くと判明しますと参考書にあるのですがエラーになってしまいそのエラー原因もわからず困っています、教えていただけますでしょうか。？

[イベント 'TestClass.ThreeEvent' は、+= または -= の左側にのみ表示されます (型 'TestClass' 内で使用する場合を除きます) ConsoleApp3 
]

```
using System;

delegate void SampleEventHandler();

class TestClass
{
    public event SampleEventHandler ThreeEvent = delegate { };
    //public event SampleEventHandler ThreeEvent = () => { };

    public void OnThreeEvent()
    {
        for(int i=1; i<=200; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);

            if(i % 3 == 0)
            {
                ThreeEvent();
            }
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        TestClass t = new TestClass();

        t.ThreeEvent += delegate { Console.WriteLine("xx"); };
        /*ここです。*/
        if (t.ThreeEvent != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }
        //t.ThreeEvent += () => Console.WriteLine("xx");
        t.OnThreeEvent();


        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

エラーメッセージ(変な日本語ですが)のとおり、イベントに対しては、それを定義したクラス(ここでは`TestClass`)の外では`+=`か`-=`でイベントハンドラの設定/解除を行うことしかできません。

```
    if (this.ThreeEvent != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }
```

と`TestClass`のメソッドの中で記述してください。

**ちなみに**

掲題のコードは何がしたいのかよくわかりませんが、よくあるのはイベント発火の前にnullチェックするコードです。

```
    if (this.ThreeEvent != null)
    {
        this.ThreeEvent();
    }
```

厳密にはこれはスレッドセーフではない(ifを通って発火するまでの間にnullになる可能性がある)ので、次にように書く必要があります。

```
    var handler = this.ThreeEvent;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler();
    }
```

これは、C#6(Visual Studio 2015)からは次のように楽に書けます。

```
    this.ThreeEvent?.Invoke();
```

Answer (score 1):

[デリゲートとイベント](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/csharp/delegates-events)は別物です。

```
public event SampleEventHandler ThreeEvent;
```

は省略形式であり本来は

```
private SampleEventHandler _threeEvent;  // 実際には_threeEventでなくアクセスできない名前
public event SampleEventHandler ThreeEvent {
  add { _threeEvent += value; }
  remove { _threeEvent -= value; }
}
```

となっています。イベント`ThreeEvent`は`+=`と`-=`しか行えず、ハンドラ設定の有無はデリゲート`_threeEvent`側を見る必要があります。
省略形式ではデリゲートには直接アクセスできないため、一旦、デリゲート変数へコピーする必要があります。

```
SampleEventHandler te = this.ThreeEvent;
if (te != null) {
    ...
}
```